# Making a GET call to Sabre

Tags: android, rest, api, http-get, sabre

I am trying to make a GET call to sabre's api. I am not receiving
data in my response and I am fairly new to httpGet/post/request.

```
public HttpResponse callGetMethod() {
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI("https://api.sabre.com/v1/shop/flights?origin=ATL&destination=LAS&departuredate=2016-08-13&returndate=2016-08-15&limit=1&enabletagging=true"));
        response = client.execute(request);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
```

I feel like I am missing just one little step somewhere.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "but I can not seem to get what I am after": if you tell us what you are after we could probably help. What does not work as expected?

Comment: Make sure to add internet permission in Manifest file. That's a common mistake for a newbie

Comment: Also if you can elaborate the error or exception or can paste your logs then we could help further

Comment: I am not receiving any data in my response. I am using an asynctask, but this is just the method that is called inside.

Comment: If it helps, the GET should be formatted like so:

Comment: GET https://api.sabre.com/v1/shop/flights?origin=ATL&destination=LAS&departuredate=2016-08-13&returndate=2016-08-15&limit=1&enabletagging=true HTTP/1.1  - EXAMPLE THEY GIVE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
string authoriazionToken = "T1RLAQILfFO0MrYdVVePW8z......";
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(new URI("https://api.sabre.com/v1/shop/flights?origin=ATL&destination=LAS&departuredate=2016-08-13&returndate=2016-08-15&limit=1&enabletagging=true"));
webRequest.Method =  "GET";
webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authoriazionToken);
webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

try
{
    WebResponse webResp = webRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(webResp.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        //Insert parsing code here
    }

}
catch.....
```

I have something of the sort for something else.

Comment: Thank you for responding to an old question here! I am not at home to give this a try, but I will let you know if this is a success later.

Comment: Not a problem, I recently faced something like you for a different thing, and this worked for me :)